# How can run this powershell script for each folder in a parent folder

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10

I have put together the following Powershell script to do the following:

1. Move all files from all the sub-folders into the root of the folder
2. Delete all sub-folders
3. Finally once all files have been moved to the root, delete any json files

My powershell script:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path ./ -Recurse -File | Move-Item -Destination ./ ; Get-ChildItem -Path ./ -Recurse -Directory | Remove-Item;

Get-ChildItem *.json | foreach { Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName }
```

I am having to use cd to change my working directory for each folder, How can I pass a folder name  and have the the above script executed for each folder.

```
--> So there is a parent folder
  --> There are 100s of Sub-Folders in the parent Folder 
      --> Each Sub-folder have many sub-folders and many files
```

How can I pass the parent folder name so it will go through each sub folder in the parent folder and run the powershell script independently for each sub-folder?

```
ParentFolder
     Child-Sub-Folder1  <-- Move all files in the sub-folders to the root folder Child-Sub-Folder1
     Child-Sub-Folder2  <-- Move all files in the sub-folders to the root folder Child-Sub-Folder2
     Child-Sub-Folder3  <-- Move all files in the sub-folders to the root folder Child-Sub-Folder3
```

Comment: Did you think about file name collisions (where two or more files have the same name, but in different subfolders), and what is wrong with adding a real path to the sourcefolder when you do `Get-ChildItem -Path <insert a real path here>` ?

Answer (score 0):

Put the processes in Foreach-Object blocks.  This lets you target the parent directory and process each subfolder in it.  This does not take into account file name collisions like @Theo commented.

```
$parentFolder = "PathToParent"

Get-ChildItem -Path $parentFolder | ForEach-Object {
    $subFolder = $_.FullName
    Get-ChildItem -Path $subFolder -Recurse -File | ForEach-Object {
        #Move-Item $_.FullName -Destination $subFolder

    }
    Get-ChildItem -Path $subFolder -Recurse -Directory | Remove-Item
    Get-ChildItem -Path $subFolder "*.json" | ForEach-Object { 
        Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
$dir = dir "D:\MyFolder\" | ?{$_.PSISContainer}

foreach ($d in $dir){
    $name =  $d.FullName 

    $name
    Get-ChildItem -Path $name -Recurse -File | Move-Item -Destination $name ; Get-ChildItem -Path $name -Recurse -Directory | Remove-Item -Confirm:$false
    Get-ChildItem -Path $name *.json | foreach { Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName } -Confirm:$false
    Get-ChildItem -Path $name *.heic | foreach { Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName } -Confirm:$false
}
```